# No overload for method 'tostring' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get my trackbar to update and print results into a text box with 2 decimal points.

The code I have here

```
widthTxt.Text = widthBar.ToString("#,0.00");
```

Keeps returning

> "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Could anyone help me figure out how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `widthBar` exactly?

Comment: Guess it should read `widthBar.Value.ToString` or something. `widthBar` seems to be a `Control`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you are missing [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property.
 `widthBar.Value.ToString("#,0.00")`

Comment: Wow this was the 5th result, normally it doesn't take this long on SO. Thanks!

Comment: `widthBar` seems to be a nullable object which is why you have to use `.Value` property to access its value. 
In that case, it is important to check that `widthBar` is not null before you access the value and convert it to a string:

`widthTxt.Text = widthBar == null ? "N/A" : widthBar.Value.ToString("F");`